# XSLT Conditional Count of text value of named attribute

Tags: xslt, count, conditional-statements

I'm pretty new to xslt but am working my way through it.  I've hit a road block with something that seems pretty simple.  I need to do a count of attributes with a certain name that have a certain value.  My XML:

```
    <wd:Bennies>
    <wd:BenefitType>Dental</wd:BenefitType>
    <wd:multidependents wd:Descriptor="Tom Thumb">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1234567890</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Dependent_ID">123456-4</wd:ID>
    </wd:multidependents>
    <wd:multidependents wd:Descriptor="Buzz LightYear">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0987654321</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Dependent_ID">123456-3</wd:ID>
    </wd:multidependents>
    <wd:multidependents wd:Descriptor="Wonder Woman">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3214567890</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Dependent_ID">123456-2</wd:ID>
    </wd:multidependents>
    <wd:multidependents wd:Descriptor="Bill Shakespeare">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">6543210789</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Dependent_ID">123456-1</wd:ID>
    </wd:multidependents>
</wd:Bennies>
<wd:Bennies>
<wd:BenefitType>Vision</wd:BenefitType>
    <wd:multidependents wd:Descriptor="Tom Thumb">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1234567890</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Dependent_ID">123456-4</wd:ID>
    </wd:multidependents>
    <wd:multidependents wd:Descriptor="Buzz LightYear">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">0987654321</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Dependent_ID">123456-3</wd:ID>
    </wd:multidependents>
    <wd:multidependents wd:Descriptor="Wonder Woman">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">3214567890</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Dependent_ID">123456-2</wd:ID>
    </wd:multidependents>
</wd:Bennies>
```

My code:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/whatever"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="DependentsSpouse" select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Bennies[wd:BenefitType = 'Vision']/wd:multidependents|/wd:Report_Data/wd:Bennies[wd:BenefitType = 'Dental']/wd:multidependents"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$DependentsSpouse">
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:ID[@wd:type='Dependent_ID']"/> <xsl:text> </xsl:text>

DEBUG
Value to count <xsl:value-of select="wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Dependent_ID']"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:variable name="DentalVisionCount" 

select="count($DependentsSpouse/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Dependent_ID'][text() = wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Dependent_ID']] )"/>
            count <xsl:value-of select="$DentalVisionCount"/>


    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The loop is there only to prove to myself that all 7 occurrences have been loaded into the variable.  The code as is returns a count of 0 even though there are 2 occurrences in the XML. The answer I want is 2.

Note that there are two wd:ID elements in each wd:multidependents element that have the wd:type attribute.  I have no control over the XML schema - it is Workday.

ADDED: Debugging values:

```
    Current 132618-1


        Values to count
        132618-4|132618-3|132618-2|132618-1|132618-3|132618-2|132618-1|
           count 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to your `count` function is actually a Boolean expression, so returns `true` or `false`

```
$DependentsSpouse/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Dependent_ID']/text()='123456-4'
```

And if you do `count(true())` the result is 1.

The expression you want is this...

```
<xsl:variable 
     name="DentalVisionCount" 
     select="count($DependentsSpouse/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Dependent_ID'][text()='123456-4'])"/>
```

Note that you can probably simplify the setting of `DependentsSpouse`

```
<xsl:variable 
     name="DependentsSpouse" 
     select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Bennies[wd:BenefitType = 'Vision' or wd:BenefitType = 'Dental']/wd:multidependents"/>
```

Comment: Well I thought it did the trick, but to simiply things my initial code example should a hardcode in place of  the node I was testing.  When I put the test of the node back in along with the suggested change, the count showed zero, even though the debugs seem to show that the values are all as they should be.  I have updated the original post.  Sorry!

Comment: Removing hard-coding is always a good idea, but I can no longer see where you are specifying the node value you wish to count exactly.

Comment: select="count($DependentsSpouse/wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Dependent_ID'][text() = wd:ID[@wd:type = 'Dependent_ID']] )"

Comment: In your question you say " though there are 2 occurrences in the XML", but you haven't really said 2 occurrences of what. That is what is confusing me now, I am afraid!

Comment: I'm afraid that I've wasted your time and it is because I left out yet another piece of information that I should have realized was pertinent!  My count was inside a for-each-group that was processing the very variable I was trying to count-up $DependentsSpouse!  The solution, you would have told me at once is to count the values in current-group():  
<xsl:variable name="DentalVisionCount" select="count(current-group()/wd:ID[@wd:type='Dependent_ID'])"/>

Thanks again and sorry.  I made your response the answer, because it did fix the coding error I presented>

Comment: Just saw your question about 2 occurrences.  I'm referring to the hardcoded value I am searching for.  in the xslt count example it was '123456-4'.  Thanks again for your help.